# Entity Framework - an object with a composite primary key

Tags: entity-framework, composite-primary-key

I'm using Entity Framework 4 and I've recently changed one of the objects' primary key to contain 2 columns instead of 1 (it used to have only its id - Guid - and now it has an id and a version - int).

When I'm trying to create another object with the same id but a different version, I get the following exception:

> *The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error
>   occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be
>   in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: AcceptChanges
>   cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another
>   object in the ObjectStateManager. Make sure that the key values are
>   unique before calling AcceptChanges.*

I looked in the database and I do have 2 objects with the same id but with different versions, like I intended.

How can I make EF cooperate with those settings?

The entity's setting from the edmx file:

```
 <EntityType Name="Test">
     <Key>
         <PropertyRef Name="TestID" />
         <PropertyRef Name="TestVersion" />
     </Key>
     <Property Type="Guid" Name="TestID" Nullable="false" />
     <Property Type="Int32" Name="FolderID" Nullable="false" />
     <Property Type="String" Name="Name" Nullable="false" MaxLength="Max" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
     <Property Type="Int32" Name="TestVersion" Nullable="false" />
     <Property Type="DateTime" Name="Date" Nullable="false" />
     <Property Type="String" Name="Owner" Nullable="false" MaxLength="Max" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
     <Property Type="Binary" Name="TestObject" Nullable="false" MaxLength="Max" FixedLength="false" />
     <NavigationProperty Name="Folder" Relationship="Labster7Model.FK_Tests_Folders" FromRole="Test" ToRole="Folder" />
     <Property Type="String" Name="Description" Nullable="false" MaxLength="Max" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
</EntityType>
```

I'll supply any other needed code parts.

**Edit:**
The table definition:
[image: table]

The guid is set in the application.

**Edit 2:**
I have 2 such objects in my DB for testing. I just saw that when looking at the context's Tests collection, it has one of them duplicated twice instead of having 2 different objects (with different versions and dates).

Comment: Did you change it in database as well? Are you correctly setting the guid in the application?

Comment: Yes and yes, please see edit for the table definition. Thanks!

Comment: This should work, but I suspect your EDMX is now incorrect. As a test, make a **new** EF model. Does it work with that?

Comment: The day after, a few lines were added to the database and it started working as expected. I hate Heisenbugs. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete all tables inside the EMDX and them re add them after updating you database this will do the drill